# Can we use the Latex to Display the math formula in android project?

Tags: javascript, android, xml

Can we use the Latex to Display the math formula in android project? if yes than how can I use give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an Android library: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView which is able to render LaTeX syntax using WebView.